# AngularJS - Posting data to API is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to send data that a user puts into a textarea and text input to and API that will save the data.

Here is the function:

```
$scope.forward = function() {

  $http({
    url: 'http://appsdev.pccportal.com:8080/ecar/api/reject/' + carID,
    method: "POST",
    data: "comments=" + this.comments,
    data: "recipient=" + this.recipient,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).
  then(function(response) {
    $scope.output = response.data;
  })

}
```

What it does when it is run is it logs only the recipient and not the comments. I am guessing because I am using "data" twice and it is only recognizing the last one (in this case "recipient"). How can I pass 2 values through this to the API.

Thanks

Comment: concat the data into one string, separated by `&`. don't forget to `encodeURIComponent`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got it working just fine:

```
data: 'recipient='+encodeURIComponent(this.recipient)+'&comments='+encodeURIComponent(this.comments),
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you're overwriting the `data` key from the plain object you're passing to `$http`, send it all together:

```js
data: { recipient: this.recipient, comments: this.comments }
```

Comment: This does not post the data to the server through the API the only thing that works is " data: "comments=" + this.comments " not " comments: this.comments "

Comment: @agon024 why do you say so? By the way, `success` is deprecated, use `then` insted. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Because the response I get back from the server is "please enter an email address that exists on the server"..and the network response for the form is {"recipient":"usersemail@ourserver.com","comments":"test"}. Instead  of recipient:usersemail@ourserver.com, comments:test, And on my other controllers that hit the server with only using comments textbox it posts to the server with a response of comments: test and the data is saved. And the only way its saves is with  data: "comments=" + this.comments. So the info is not saved in the DB.

Comment: @agon024 well, this is odd. Are you sure that the problem is on how do you send the params? Look in the link I posted before that this is a valid way to send them, also the error you pasted says only that the received email is not in the database. Why don't you print the received params on the server side? I think the problem is there

Comment: {"recipient":"usersemail@ourserver.com","comments":"test"} is what is coming back when it should be recipient: usersemail@ourserver.com, comments: test.

Comment: @agon024 How does your server parses the request? Because the data is obviously getting there (and in a cleaner way that you're asking for, because it's easier to work with an object instead of strings) but you're not being able to parse it, what's your backend doing with the response? (Btw `$http` works with promises, you should use `then`, look: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121274/discussion-between-agon024-and-martriay).

Answer (score 0):

pass it as an object:

```
data : {comments: this.comments, recipient: this recipient}
```

Comment: As i posted below, this does not post the data to the server through the API the only thing that works is " data: "comments=" + this.comments " not " comments: this.comments "